# Saving an interactive plot with information about the data series using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a question related to plots created by `matplotlib`. I have a GUI (in python) which creates plots from `*.mat` files, it saves the plots as a `*.JPG file`. A sample plot Looks as follows:
[image]

Now as you can see there are two data series present in the plot, and now i want to save the plot like an `Excel plot` **where i can interact with the plot and also obtain the Location of the *.mat file from which it was created**.

Can this be done using Python? I need ideas from you guys

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to save the plot **as** an Excel file? Or else what file format do you envision? If you already have the GUI to load and show the data-files it seems that this GUI is exactly what you're asking for, so I have trouble understanding what you're asking.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, Well after saving the plots as *.JPG files i will loose Information from which data i generated the plots. I mean if i open the plots after few days and i want to know from which data i generated the Graphs, i should have the possibility to go to the data from which it was generated, like the charts in Excel or like *.fig files which Show me the data of the plots

Comment: I see the problem, but that could also simply be solved by organizing your workflow better. What exactly is the question you're having here?

Comment: I would like to know if i could generate something like *.fig file (instead of *.jpg) which could basically have links to the *.mat files from which the plots are created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are of course a lot of different options to save a file containing additional information. To list a few:

- Using the EXIF tags of a jpg image to store the filenames. This might require a library like [piexif](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/piexif).
- Saving a dictionary like `{"files" : ["filename1", "filename2"], "image" : <imagedata>}` to a file, where `<imagedata>` could be the raw image or a numpy array of the image data.
- Pickling a dictionary like `{"files" : ["filename1", "filename2"], "image" : <figure>}`, where `figure` is the matplotlib figure object.

At the end it might be much easier to just create a lookup table with image filenames and raw data filenames to see which image belongs to which data.